# when installing cocoa pods in project i get this error ld: library not found for -lBolts

Tags: ios, xcode

im getting this error when trying to build my xcode project.

```
ld: library not found for -lBolts
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I cant figure out what the issue is.

Comment: Which Pod did you install? Seems that one added "-lBolts" flag for Bolts lib.

Comment: Make sure you did open xcworkspace, not xcproj file.

Comment: yes im opening xcworkspace.

Comment: Can you paste the podfile text?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/fDtdkK70

Comment: In your project/Build Settings/Other Linker Flags, there should be a "-lBolts". Did you put it yourself? Did you try to update the pods (pod update)? An old pods Bolts ? Maybe on a new empty project add them one by one until you find the culprit?